# How to find out which c++ standard used in a binary file?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc

For example, I have a "helloworld" cpp  file named main.cpp.
If I compile it with flag -std=c++11. And I compile it again with flag -std=c++03.
How can I specify which is compiled with c++11 flag between this two?
**extra:** My specific problem is that I have a third-party lib file, I used it in my code, but I don't know which "-std" flag should I use.

Comment: It's most likely impossible in general case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Well, you could place kinda indicator string in the binary.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ,  I mean compile with different c++ standard won't leave something in the binary filie?

Comment: *"I have a third-party lib file"* then you should also have a corresponding header file and documentation explaining compatibility.

Comment: How is that a problem? Compile your code with the language version it was written for.

Comment: @Riopho No, it won't unless you provide such yourself in your own code.

Comment: In general, it is not possible.  Compilers don't typically save information to object or executables identifying the language version of the source code.   However, it is possible in source code to test predefined macros (e.g. conditionally use different code based on the value that the predefined macro `__cplusplus` to determine the C++ language standard) and embed appropriate information.

Comment: Welcome on SO. A valuable third party-libary may either be self-contained (works in any standard which is able to accept the header files), or should provide some piece of doc. which mentions compatibility concerns. In the case of VisualStudio/VC++, there exists a similar issue, that C++ libaries have to be provided for each VC++ version/runtime-library they are intended to support, as there is no binary-compatibility between C++ code compiled with distinct versions. In gcc, it might be not that drastical but I must admit I'm not that experienced for gcc...

Comment: Regarding the comment of @πάνταῥεῖ, a standard conforming C++ compiler has to provide some predefined macros. One of them is [`__cpluplus`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html). It can be used to check in code whether it is compiled on a C++ compiler. (This is used in C APIs where header files are intended to be usable in C and C++.) Additionally, it provides a number which provides info about the used standard. You may switch standard and language in this small demo: [**Live Demo on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NSNtk3kiuiNxHftz).

Answer (score 0):

1. If it is a third party library, then there must be some documentation stating the compilation steps to build from source. Please refer that.
2. If there is no such thing available, I am assuming that you at least have access to the source code, please look into the implementation (the header files or the source files), you will probably get more than enough information to figure out if it uses code conforming to C++ 11 standard.

> @πάνταῥεῖ,I mean compile with different c++ standard won't leave something in the binary filie? - `Riopho`

If you want to figure out from binary, then I would probably use objdump and disassemble the binary with demangling turned on - `objdump -dC <binary_name>` - (assuming that you are on Linux, don't know much windows though). you should be able to get some hint from that.

I am not sure if the compiler leaves any traces in the binary though.